# Log output of PowerShell psdebug trace to a file

Tags: powershell, debugging, trace

1. I have a **script "B"** from which I want to capture the debug
   output of `Set-PSDebug -Trace n` **to a file.** (*File* is the
   keyword here.)
2. I need to **initiate** the execution and debug capture of script "**B**" from **another script**, called **A**.

Example:

Script **B**:

```
Set-PSDebug -Trace 1

Function FuncA {
    Write-Host "ABC"
    FuncB
}

Function FuncB {
    Write-Host "123"
}

FuncA
FuncB
```

The **correct** debug output of this is:

```
DEBUG:   15+  >>>> FuncA
DEBUG:    6+ Function FuncA  >>>> {
DEBUG:    7+      >>>> Write-Host "ABC"
ABC
DEBUG:    8+      >>>> FuncB
DEBUG:   11+ Function FuncB  >>>> {
DEBUG:   12+      >>>> Write-Host "123"
123
DEBUG:   13+  >>>> }
DEBUG:    9+  >>>> }
DEBUG:   16+  >>>> FuncB
DEBUG:   11+ Function FuncB  >>>> {
DEBUG:   12+      >>>> Write-Host "123"
123
DEBUG:   13+  >>>> }
```

.

But when I try to run it now from script **A** via start-process to capture the output to a file:

```
$SParguments = "-NoProfile -file `"$stdTracefile`""
Start-Process 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' -ArgumentList $SParguments -RedirectStandardOutput $stdTracelog
```

the output is oddly just this:

```
DEBUG:   15+  >>>> FuncA
DEBUG:    6+ Function FuncA  >>>> {
DEBUG:    7+      >>>> Write-Host "ABC"
ABC
123
123
```

The debugging messages stop after the first function, although the script finishes correctly.

**Any ideas why and how to circumvent or avoid this?**

**Alternatively, I am looking for another solution to reach the two goals stated at the top.**

*BTW: I also tried using `trace-command`, which has a `filepath` parameter, but I don't know how to **trace a whole script**, and I do not know how to get the information Set-PSDebug provides: the lines being executed and the **commands** being executed, **without all the rest**.*
I want to automatically process the debug output, and the output of Set-PSDebug is exactly what I need.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem, neither from the PowerShell console nor the ISE.  I always get the **correct** output you listed, minus a carriage return or two.  Which version of PowerShell are you running (available in the `$PSVersionTable` variable)?

Comment: Also, instead of spinning up PowerShell with Start-Process, what happens if you just call it directly, using `.\b.ps1`?

Comment: I use v4 and after your comment just tried it on v3. Same result. I tried the console, ISE and PowerGUI.
Dot-sourcing is not an option because 1. i dont wont the script in my runspace , but more important redirection of the debug output to a file does not work fully, because redirection with  "5>" does not include the line numbers of the trace and they are vital for me.

Comment: Just tested it on v5, which works. And has way more output, btw. :/ So this might be a bug.
Unfortunately using v5 is not possible, it need to find a solution for v4.
Maybe there is another way to redirect the output to a file, apart from Start-process....

Comment: I don't think it's a bug... I suspect that `Set-PSDebug` uses `Write-Host`.  PowerShell 5.0 changed the way `Write-Host` works (it now writes to the [**Information Stream**, aka stream 6](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/07/04/weekend-scripter-welcome-to-the-powershell-information-stream/)).  However, even running your example with PowerShell 2.0 still didn't recreate the bug on my end.  Sorry.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, dot-sourcing would be `. .\b.ps1`, with an extra dot.  The lone dot in `.\b.ps1` is the current-directory dot and just runs the script while keeping it out of your runspace.  Good luck.

Comment: The fact that you could not reproduce it, makes me wonder if there is still a chance this might work after all. But i can not image how, i tested this on three different VMs with different OS and Posh versions. 
**Could** you tell me exactly how you tested it? You did create **two scripts** with the code shown above, right? (You should have only had to add two lines to script A with the paths for the variables for tracefile and tracelog.)

Comment: And about the running of the script directly: how do i get the output of the trace into the logfile then?

Answer (score 3):

So, here's what I learned with some testing in PowerShell v4.0, using both the ISE and the regular host.

1. Using *any* of the `Write-` cmdlets seemed to interrupt the PSDebug output from the point that the first of those cmdlets is encountered. Commenting them out, e.g. the `Write-Host "ABC"` line would allow more trace to be seen until the `Write-Host` in FuncB was called.
2. Using `return` fixed the problem, although it did mean that FuncB wasn't called from within FuncA, simply due to the logical flow of the script.
3. Stripping things back to just the string itself seemed to result in the expected behaviour. By this I mean simply removing the `Write-Host` cmdlet and leaving the `"ABC"` and `"123"` parts. I'm not fan in spitting out text like this from functions, but at least it gave what we're expecting in this example. See below.
4. Leaving a blank line at the end of Script A changed the behaviour of the output, i.e. if there is a carriage return at the end of line 13 then the output is formatted as shown below. If not, then you'd end up with two lines of debug on the same line:

   DEBUG:   13+  >>>> FuncBDEBUG:    8+ Function FuncB  >>>> {
5. Running in PowerShell 5.0 mostly fixes the (original post) problem, although I still had problems with DEBUG lines running on immediately after the Write-Host output (i.e. without a newline). Again, switching to the code in the solution below fixed the output.

   ABCDEBUG:    5+    >>>> FuncB

### Solution

**Script A**: *C:\Scripts\PowerShell\Test-Debug.ps1*

```
Set-PSDebug -Trace 1

Function FuncA {
    "ABC"
    FuncB
}

Function FuncB {
    "123"
}

FuncA
FuncB
```

**Script B**: : *C:\Scripts\PowerShell\Call-TestDebug.ps1*

```
$stdTraceFile = "C:\Scripts\PowerShell\Test-Debug.ps1"
$stdTraceLog  = Join-Path $env:TEMP test.log

$PSExecutable = 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
$SParguments = "-Version 4 -NoProfile -File $stdTracefile"

Start-Process -FilePath $PSExecutable -ArgumentList $SParguments `
  -RedirectStandardOutput $stdTracelog
```

This gave the output that I think you were expecting in **test.log**:

```
DEBUG:   12+  >>>> FuncA
DEBUG:    3+ Function FuncA  >>>> {
DEBUG:    4+      >>>> "ABC"
ABC
DEBUG:    5+      >>>> FuncB
DEBUG:    8+ Function FuncB  >>>> {
DEBUG:    9+      >>>> "123"
123
DEBUG:   10+  >>>> }
DEBUG:    6+  >>>> }
DEBUG:   13+  >>>> FuncB
DEBUG:    8+ Function FuncB  >>>> {
DEBUG:    9+      >>>> "123"
123
DEBUG:   10+  >>>> }
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but Script B was of course just an example. This needs to work with multiple scripts which i can not edit.

Comment: Hah. Then I'll add a different answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Use PowerShell 5!

I have had a quick look on MS Connect to see if there is any hint of this being a known/reported bug but haven't found anything. HOWEVER, the fact that the behaviour changes in PSv5 suggests that there has been a fix, possibly with the introduction of the Information output stream.

If you can't modify the scripts which are currently calling `Write-Host`, etc. then, from our collective testing, I'm not sure there is a fix other than to use PowerShell 5. Obviously not a trivial proposal if you have a large/controlled environment.

Comment: I know that it works with v5, I said that in the comments to my OP. But an upgrade to v5 is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. However this might be a workable answer for someone else who stumbles upon this question... :-)

Answer (score 0):

The module [PowerShellLogging](https://github.com/dlwyatt/PowerShellLoggingModule) might get some new project resources/a hand over, that will bring it up-to-date with the latest releases of PowerShell..